# Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API - Waiting infinitely

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I`m trying to use Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API.

I converted mp3 audio file format to .raw as I understood from API documentation, and uploaded to bucket storage.

Here is my code:

```
def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri):
    """Asynchronously transcribes the audio file specified by the gcs_uri."""
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US')

    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

    print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
    response = operation.result()

    # Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
    # them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
    for result in response.results:
        # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
        print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
        print('Confidence: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))

transcribe_gcs("gs://cloudh3-200314.appspot.com/cs.raw")
```

What I`m doing wrong?

Comment: so what is the error message?

Comment: It`s just the problem that waiting never ends.

Comment: Could you try doing this same operation with the same file directly with the [API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/longrunningrecognize) and later check how the operation is running [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/operations/get). Bypassing the library will clarify where the actually issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, this is something to do with the format that is acceptable. Even though you may have converted into RAW, there still could be something wrong with the format, it wouldn't give you output if it can't read the file.

I recently processed a 56 min audio that took 17 mins so that should give you an idea of how long it should be.

Process your file using sox, I found the conversion parameters that work using the command -

```
sox basefile.mp3 -r 16000 -c 1 newfile.flac
```